# Save a Spark Dataframe to couchbase

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, couchbase

I want to write spark dataframe data to couchbase. For this, I am trying to do it as follows:-

```
double[] val=new double[3]; 
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("sql").setMaster("local").set("com.couchbase.nodes", "url_of_couchbase").set("com.couchbase.bucket.bucket_name", "password"));
SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sql.read().json("sample.json");
df.registerTempTable("sample");

DataFrame men=sql.sql("select mean(imp_recall_interval) from sample");
Row[] r=men.collect();
val[0]=Double.parseDouble(r[0].toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").trim());
JsonDocument doc1=JsonDocument.create("docId", JsonObject.create().put("mean", val[0]));
System.out.println("Data Saved");
JsonArrayDocument jrd=JsonArrayDocument.create("imp_recall_timeinterval_mean_median_sd", JsonArray.from("more", "content", "in", "here"));
```

But when i try to parrallelize these, i am not able to do that.

```
 sc.parrallelize(Seq(doc1,jrd));
```

Please tell me how can i save this data to couchbase. Or please specify other methods also by which i can create a create and save the document in Couchbase

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.couchbase.spark.japi.CouchbaseDocumentRDD;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.AbstractDocument;


JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(jsc);

JsonDocument doc1;
JsonArrayDocument jrd;

List<AbstractDocument> list = new ArrayList<AbstractDocument>();
list.add(doc1);
list.add(jrd);

JavaRDD<AbstractDocument> jRDD = jsc.parallelize(list);
CouchbaseDocumentRDD<AbstractDocument> cbRDD = CouchbaseDocumentRDD.couchbaseDocumentRDD(jRDD);
cbRDD.saveToCouchbase();
```

Comment: what is the impot for List .

Comment: Added imports in answer above.

Comment: Build Failure. When i try to compile the code. Compiltation Fails. com.couchbase.client.java.document.AbstractDocument is not within bounds of type-variable T.

Comment: could you please suggest the couchbase connectivity using CouchbaseCluster.

Comment: How to parallelize and save json document to Couchbase database using spark works fine with the code I have provided. I have tested this code. Post separate question for connectivity with CouchbaseCluster and provide details and issues you are getting.